# how to measure power consumption for arduino circuit

Tags: arduino, battery

what is the best way to define the battery size for a stand alone arduino circuits which include a 5V pro mini, esp866 WiFi module and a temperature sensor. I need the battery to support the system for 1year and the WiFi module will send out data for every 15 mins. I did plug it in to a power supplier adopter and then hook it up with the energy smart metre but it was not sensitive enough to detect the energy consumption ( e.g. power rate: 0.7W, energy consumption: 0 for 10hrs). So what sort of components do I need and how, please help, thank you very much. [image]

Answer (score 2):

There's an open source circuit for measuring very small currents, which has been written up in Nuts and Volts magazine and Silicon Chip magazine. If you want a precise measure of power consumption, that circuit may do what you want.  See http://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/

If you instead want a rough idea of power consumption, I like the idea of using a fairly small battery with known power, and measuring how long it takes your circuit to drain that battery.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a tiny and cheap battery with specified capacity and measured a time needed to discharge it.

Comment: Make sure you check the specs and find out the shelf discharge rate of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using components designed for use in commercially marketed equipment (Wifi, etc), you should have good specs with regards to power, etc. Were I in your shoes, I'd get the specs for the basic Arduino, memory, WiFi, networking and temperature sensor. Over spec things by at least two, preferably four, and use that to calculate your battery capacity. Then I'd find a battery that meets my requirements, factoring in shelf-life losses, etc.

The Arduino should be very constant in terms of its energy usage though you should check on whether there are special power states that it might drop into. I don't think there are but you never know.

To test, find the biggest energy hog; my suspicion is that it's the WiFi by an order of magnitude. Then increase the hog's (e.g. WiFi) usage rate by a factor of ten and measure the energy consumption (perhaps by using the smaller battery suggested by others).

Other factors to consider are power saving states of the WiFi and other peripherals, but that should just make your estimates more conservative.